# Stuck with "IF" statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to have a certain div have a display style of "none" if it's referencing a div that has a display style of "block", for example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("first_question");
var y = document.getElementById("second_question");

if (x.style.display = "block") {
y.style.display = "none";
}
```

However, I have two buttons in the "first_question" div that depending on which one is pressed, should change the style.display of "second_question" to "block":

```
function button() {
y.style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
  <div id="first_question">
    <p>This is question #1</p>

      <input type="button" onclick="button()"  value="button">
      <input type="button" onclick="whatever()" value="whatever">

  </div>

  <div id="second_question">
    <p>This is question #2</p>

      <input type="button" onclick="option1()" value="option1">
      <input type="button" value="option2">

  </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a Sample runnable code snippet

Comment: `x.style.display = "block"` is not checking equality, it is _assigning_ the value `"block"` to `x.style.display`; to check equality, in JS, your best bet is the [strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

Comment: if(x.style.display === "block"){// needs to done}

Comment: @Vishnudev here's a runnable code: https://jsfiddle.net/fjkb6gy2/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think I may see the problem:

```
if (x.style.display = "block") {
y.style.display = "none";
}
```

Here, you use a single = sign instead of two or three (see edit). That means that the code will *always* set x to have a display of block and that because of how values can be "truthy" in javascript, the if statement will evaluate to be true, and y will *always* have its display set to none.

**Edit:**

Originally I wrote that a single equal sign was used instead of two. However, it is best practice to use three equal signs in javascript (and I often forget this too being primarily a Java programmer). This is because it forces type checking, which prevents weird behavior that can be found here: https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs#-is-equal-

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't this work? (https://jsfiddle.net/fjkb6gy2/) My question #2 is supposed to be hidden until "button" is pressed in question #1.